# I am not able to add more icons inside material calendar in android

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar, calendarview

[image: I want to make similar like this image]I am working on the android material calendar I am making a pregnancy calendar in that if I will click on one-day selection next some days add automatically icon inside here is my code :

```
   calendarView.setOnDayClickListener(new OnDayClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDayClick(EventDay eventDay) {

            Calendar clickedDayCalendar = eventDay.getCalendar();
            /*      clickedDayCalendar.set( clickedDayCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH + 4) ,  clickedDayCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) , clickedDayCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));*/
            events.add(new EventDay(clickedDayCalendar, R.drawable.sample_icon_2));

            ArrayList<String> eventDays = new ArrayList<String>();


            calendarView.setEvents(events);



        /*    alert_diaog_picker(eventDay.getCalendar().getTime().toString());*/


         //   Calendar clickedDayCalendar = eventDay.getCalendar();
         /*   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Selected Date:\n" + "Day = " + clickedDayCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) +
                    "\n" + "Month = " + clickedDayCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "\n" + "Year = " + clickedDayCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
        }
    });



    return view;
}
```

here is my xml code:

```
<com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:abbreviationsBarColor="#303F9F"
    app:abbreviationsLabelsColor="@android:color/white"
    app:daysLabelsColor="@android:color/white"
    app:headerColor="#1A237E"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:pagesColor="#3F51B5"
    app:eventsEnabled="false"
    app:selectionColor="@android:color/white"
    app:selectionLabelColor="#3F51B5"
    app:anotherMonthsDaysLabelsColor="#3F51B5"
    app:todayLabelColor="#AEEA00"
    app:type="many_days_picker" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/getDateButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get date"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/calendarView" />
```

```
implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.6.0'
```

now  it's working like when I click on the date it includes icon only on that date but I want to add an icon on another next four days please help me thank you in advance I appreciate every answer

Comment: I have done already

Comment: on click day I want to put icon in next 4 days